# how to update values in arrays using function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am a beginner at C. I want to update a the values of elements in a single line  array to a new array using a function, but I'm stuck with 2 problems:

1. I don't really know how to pass the array to a function and then access it
2. Don't know how to update the new elements to a new array (inside the function) and then print the new one

Answer (score 3):

You can not pass **array**, but you can pass **pointer** to the first element of array. It helps to look for **pointer array arithmetic** on web.

example function that fills B with values from A multiplied by two:

```
int func(int *A, int *B, int size){
    for(int x = 0; x<size, x++){
        B[x] = 2*A[x]
    }
}
```

Calling that function:

```
func(a,b,5);
```

or you can take the first element of array A[0] and than de-reference it(take address of that element)

```
func(&a[0],&b[0],5)
```

Both of these calls do the same, it just use different syntax.